# 'invalidate' in 'PagingSource' is final and cannot be overridden [Android Kotlin]?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, android-paging-library

I've just started in android development. I saw a project on github that use Retrofit to call Deezer Api and I want to implement it to my project but i ran into a trouble in the PagingSource class, here the PagingSource class :

```
package com.example.myapplication.data.remote.paging

import androidx.paging.PagingSource
import com.example.myapplication.data.models.ResponseData
import com.example.myapplication.data.models.album.Album
import com.example.myapplication.data.models.artist.Artist
import com.example.myapplication.data.models.tracks.Track
import com.example.myapplication.data.remote.paging.PagingDataSource
import com.example.myapplication.data.services.ServiceType
import retrofit2.HttpException
import java.io.IOException
abstract class PagingRepository(
private val query: String,
private val serviceType: ServiceType,
private val pagingDataSource: PagingDataSource
) : PagingSource\<Int, ResponseData\>() {

    companion object {
        private val inMemoryCache =
            mutableListOf<ResponseData>() // (*) we don't care about the object type
        private val queryCache = mutableListOf<String>()
    }
    
    private val startPage = 0
    private val limit = 25
    
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, ResponseData> {
        val position = params.key ?: startPage
        val apiQuery = query
        return try {
    
            val oldQuery = queryCache.find {
                apiQuery.equals(it, true)
            }
    
            if (oldQuery != null && position == startPage) {
                val validatedResults = resultsValidatedAndSorted(apiQuery)
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = validatedResults,
                    prevKey = null,
                    nextKey = null
                )
            } else {
                val response = when (serviceType) {
                    ServiceType.Artists -> pagingDataSource.fetchArtist(apiQuery, position * limit, limit)
                    ServiceType.Albums -> pagingDataSource.fetchAlbum(apiQuery, position * limit, limit)
                    ServiceType.Tracks -> pagingDataSource.fetchTrack(apiQuery, position * limit, limit)
                }
                val body = response.body()!!
                val results = response.body()!!.data
    
                queryCache.add(apiQuery)
    
                val shelled = results.map { ResponseData(query = apiQuery, data = it) }
    
                inMemoryCache.addAll(
                    shelled
                )
    
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = if (position * limit <= body.total) shelled else emptyList(),
                    prevKey = if (position == startPage) null else position - 1,
                    nextKey = if (shelled.isEmpty() || position * limit > body.total) null else position + 1
                )
            }
    
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }
    
    private fun resultsValidatedAndSorted(query: String): List<ResponseData> {
        return inMemoryCache.filter {
            it.query.contains(query, true)
        }
    }
    
    override fun invalidate()
    {
        super.invalidate()
        inMemoryCache.clear()
        queryCache.clear()
    }

}
```

**error** : 'invalidate' in 'PagingSource' is final and cannot be overridden

Here my gradle file :

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'kotlin-android'

    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'

}

android {
namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
       // buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
        def secureProps = new Properties()
        if (file("../secure.properties").exists()) {
            file("../secure.properties")?.withInputStream { secureProps.load(it) }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", (secureProps.getProperty("BASE_URL") ?: "")
        buildConfigField "String", "SECRET", (secureProps.getProperty("SECRET") ?: "")
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += ["-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"] // opt in for experimental functions
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
      dataBinding = true
    }

}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.4.5'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
//paging
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-common-ktx:3.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha10'
//navigation
def nav_version ="2.5.3"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    // - - ViewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.1'
    //bottomNavigation
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    //splashscreen
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
    // -- retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1"
    //implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1"
    
    // HILT
    def hilt_version = "2.45"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
    
    "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    // Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'
    // ExoPlayer
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.5"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.5"
    api "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.18.5"
    
    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.5'
    
    // Firebase Storage KTX
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.1.0'
    
    // Firebase Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4'
    
    
    
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.6.0'
    
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.2.1'
    // Coil Image Loading Library
    implementation('io.coil-kt:coil:1.1.0')
    // Subtitle supported collapsing toolbar
    implementation 'com.hendraanggrian.material:collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle:1.1.0'
    
    // Flow Binding
    implementation 'io.github.reactivecircus.flowbinding:flowbinding-android:0.10.2'
    
    implementation('androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1')

}
kapt {
correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

But when I remove the overide fun invalidate() to fun invalidate() it has another error : "'invalidate' hides member of supertype 'PagingSource' and needs 'override' modifier"

Comment: Is this right Syntax with \ in `: PagingSource\<Int, ResponseData\>() {` I'm wondering why this compile

Answer (score 0):

So the reason for the behaviour is that `PagingSource` is abstract. It is declared like this:

```
public abstract class PagingSource<Key : Any, Value : Any> {
```

From an abstract class [you can not create a object.](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/abstract-class)

So if you want to call `invalidate` it is interpret as a final (static) method. You can not override finals. But if you don't write the `override` modifier you hide the `invalidate` function from `PagingSource`. This is not allowed.

To be precise. `fun invalidate` should have declared as `abstract fun invalide()` Then you must implement the function via override.

But `invalidate()` is declared like this and a real implementation in `PagingSource`

```
 public fun invalidate() {
   // implementation
 }
```

I can not solve your code because I don't know what should happen when and so on. If you just need an invalidate which you can call like this:

`pagingRepository.invalidate()`

Then just create another function like this

`pagingRepository.invalidatePaging()`

```
fun invalidatePager() {
  this.invalidate() // this should have the same effect like your planned override
  inMemoryCache.clear()
  queryCache.clear()
}
```

But again I don't know enough code and the architecture of your example.
If you want to dive deep then do [a google lab for paging.](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#0)